# Unable to locate element python selenium - Need to click this button

Tags: python, selenium, find, element

So, this button has no id/name and I've tried xpath, class name, CSS selector, etc

Here is the HTML code:

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to switchTo the iframe that contains this button!  Then I think that this CSS path should work:

```
div.submit-and-reset-wrapper button.continue
```

Comment: Yeah.. that was it, did not realize that I needed to swith to iframe.. now it's working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try a kind of ugly hack:

- get all the button/span elements
- loop all the button/span elements until you find the text.

  - then click the element...

something like:

```
all_span_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("span")
for span_element in all_span_elements:
    if "Begin Lesson" in span_element.text:
        span_element.click()
```